# Merging SpatialPointsDataFrame to SpatialPolygonsDataFrame in R

Tags: r, point, merge

I am trying to perform a spatial join between SpatialPointsDataFrame and SpatialPolygonsDataFrame.

I have two sets of data named California_shp and Houses. Their information is as follow:

```
dput(head(California_shp))
structure(list(NAME = 1:6), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

class(California_shp)
    [1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
    attr(,"package")
    [1] "sp" 


dput(head(Houses))
structure(list(houseValue = c(452600L, 358500L, 352100L, 341300L, 
342200L, 269700L), income = c(8.3252, 8.3014, 7.2574, 5.6431, 
3.8462, 4.0368), houseAge = c(41L, 21L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L), 
    rooms = c(880L, 7099L, 1467L, 1274L, 1627L, 919L), bedrooms = c(129L, 
    1106L, 190L, 235L, 280L, 213L), population = c(322L, 2401L, 
    496L, 558L, 565L, 413L), households = c(126L, 1138L, 177L, 
    219L, 259L, 193L), latitude = c(37.88, 37.86, 37.85, 37.85, 
    37.85, 37.85), longitude = c(-122.23, -122.22, -122.24, -122.25, 
    -122.25, -122.25)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

class(Houses)
    [1] "SpatialPointsDataFrame"
    attr(,"package")
    [1] "sp"
```

How by using the point-in-polygon operation and the mean function, I can merge the Houses object to California_shp?

I have written and runed the following codes in R:

```
library(spatialEco)

library(sp)

head(California_shp@data)
       NAME
1   Alameda
2    Alpine
3    Amador
4     Butte
5 Calaveras
6    Colusa

head(Houses@data)
      houseValue income houseAge rooms bedrooms population households latitude longitude
    1     452600 8.3252       41   880      129        322        126    37.88   -122.23
    2     358500 8.3014       21  7099     1106       2401       1138    37.86   -122.22
    3     352100 7.2574       52  1467      190        496        177    37.85   -122.24
    4     341300 5.6431       52  1274      235        558        219    37.85   -122.25
    5     342200 3.8462       52  1627      280        565        259    37.85   -122.25
    6     269700 4.0368       52   919      213        413        193    37.85   -122.25
    
pts.poly <- point.in.poly(Houses,California_shp)
    
pts.poly
    class       : SpatialPointsDataFrame 
    features    : 20640 
    extent      : -124.35, -114.31, 32.54, 41.95  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
    crs         : +proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs 
    variables   : 10
    names       : houseValue,  income, houseAge, rooms, bedrooms, population, households, latitude, longitude, NAME 
    min values  :      14999,  0.4999,        1,     2,        1,          3,          1,    32.54,   -124.35,    1 
    max values  :     500001, 15.0001,       52, 39320,     6445,      35682,       6082,    41.95,   -114.31,   58
```

Unfortunately, it does not still help me. I need to improve them.

Comment: I would encourage you to work through the examples in `?spatialEco::point.in.poly`, in particularity the `tapply` example where counts are aggregated to the polygons. The same would apply for calculating an aggregated mean. In fact, all you would do is substute `tapply(pts.poly.dup$IDS.x, pts.poly.dup$IDS.y, FUN=mean)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are showing only partial information in your post regarding the data. For example, if I run, as per your example,

```
library(sp)
California_shp = structure(list(NAME = 1:6), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
class(California_shp)
[1] "data.frame"
```

But you show this:

```
class(California_shp)
    [1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
    attr(,"package")
    [1] "sp"
```

How did `Californai_shp` become a spatial object? Something else is going on that you're not showing us. Same regarding `Houses`. Can we get the full output of:

`str(California_shp)` and `str(Houses)`

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways one could accomplish what you are after but, here is a way that is in line with what you have already tried.

We will use the North Carolina polygon data and a random point sample to approximate your data. The data we want to aggregate to the polygons is "y", representing a random uniform distribution.

```
library(sf)
library(sp)
library(spatialEco)

poly <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) 
  pts <- st_sf(st_sample(poly, 1000))
    pts$y <- runif(nrow(pts))
```

Here we just coerce to an sp class to be consistent with your code but, sf would work as well.

```
poly <- as(poly, "Spatial")
pts <- as(pts, "Spatial")
```

Now, we call a point in polygon function.

```
( pip <- spatialEco::point.in.poly(pts, poly) )
```

If every polygon has a point associated with it then everything is ordered and a new variable can just be assigned.

```
poly@data$y <- tapply(pip$y, pip$NAME, mean)
  spplot(poly, "y")
```

However, if not all polygons contain points then, you will have to add the extra steps of creating a data.frame and performing a join using `sp::merge`, `dplyr::left_join`, etc...

To illustrate this we, remove a county

```
pip <- pip[-which(pip$NAME == "Johnston"),]
```

Aggregate the data and create a data.frame with NAME from the `tapply` object. When we check the number of observations, between `a` and `polys`, we see that they are not equal.

```
( a <- tapply(pip$y, pip$NAME, mean) ) 
( a <- data.frame(NAME=names(a), y=as.vector(a)) )

nrow(poly) == nrow(a)
```

Finally, we join to polygon data.

```
poly@data <- dplyr::left_join(poly@data, a, "NAME")
  spplot(poly, "y")
```

To operate on an sf object just omit the @data slot call.